# Redirected you too many times

Tags: coldfusion, isapi-rewrite

I have a link on the site I'm working on that is giving me issues in chrome. In firefox and ie (I will never say this again) is working as it should, but chrome is showing me this message.

[image]

And it's not quite making sense. There is only one redirect going on after you click on the site. Is there anyway to fix this in Chrome? I have cleared my history/cookies/cache.

I will provide as much info as I can, but at this moment I'm not sure what to include to help.

Comment: Open the developer toolbar in Chrome, goto `Network`, check `Preserve log`, visit your site, filter result by `Doc` and check what redirects you with what status code (e.g. 301, 302, 303). `303 See Other` is the only redirect that is not supposed to be cached. `301 Moved Permanently` **will** and `302 Moved Temporarily` **may** be cached. Safari does it too and will probably behave the same as Chrome here.

Comment: I only see one redirect happening in the network tab. However, I did find this in the isapi redirect file.

Could this be causing it? RewriteRule ^blog/index.cfm/(.*) /blog/index.cfm/$1/ [R=301,L]

Comment: Comment out that RewriteRule and see if the issue goes away. It looks suspect though because the redirect is directing back to the same URL of the rewrite rule.

Comment: @Miguel-F That seemed to work for a while, however it's now giving me the same message. It's being weird and intermittent